# Not able to install evolution on Ubuntu 20.04. New to computers. Demonstrate step by step procedure

Tags: 20.04

New to Ubuntu terminal and the commands. Would like step by step procedure to install evolution on UBUNTU 20.04 on AMD64 processor computer.

Answer (score 3):

Thunderbird is stable and cross platform. Thunderbird is the default mail application in Ubuntu 20.04, but if you want to install Evolution instead open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install evolution
```

Comment: If you want Evolution to become the new default, after installation you will also have to go to Settings -> Default Applications and set Evolution instead of Thunderbird as default mail application there.

Comment: Evolution seems not to work using Ubuntu 20.04…

Comment: I'm happy with Thunderbird in 20.04, but I haven't been happy with Evolution since Ubuntu 12.04.