# 20.04 on XPS13: Chrome hangs, Firefox OK; Evolution loses authentication, Thunderbird OK

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, evolution, xps

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an old XPS 13 9343. The installation was a little painful: using Rufus to put the ISO on a USB stick (as suggested in the Ubuntu tutorials) led to no Wi-Fi. I fixed that by swapping to Universal USB Installer.

I now have Wi-Fi. The thing that is confusing me is that some apps work, while other very similar apps do not. For example, Chrome works when I install it, but after restarting the machine it fails. It is still clearly able to connect to the network because it auto-completes searches as I type, but it fails to load any web pages, it just sits there. The spinning loading icon is stuck too. But Firefox works without issue.

I have the same dichotomy with email. Thunderbird works fine, but GNOME's Evolution only works when I install it. After restarting the machine it loses authentication with each of my email accounts. Again it clearly still has network access since reconnecting an account kicks off the two factor authentication on my phone, but then it hangs at "Requesting access token, please wait..."

How come one browser works, and one does not, and one email client works, and one does not? I would expect networking issues to affect everything in a similar way. How might I diagnose and fix this?

===== EDIT =====

Following [T Br](https://askubuntu.com/users/1383491/t-br)'s suggestion in a [comment on an answer below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367354/20-04-on-xps13-chrome-hangs-firefox-ok-evolution-loses-authentication-thunde/1367901#comment2350945_1367901) here is the `tail -f /var/log/syslog` output. Not that these lines were written while Chrome was still responsive, no additional errors were written as it hung.

```
Oct 12 09:57:40 tim-XPS-13-9343 systemd[844]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.  
Oct 12 09:57:40 tim-XPS-13-9343 gnome-shell[6136]: [6177:6177:1012/095740.540338:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is  
Oct 12 09:57:40 tim-XPS-13-9343 gnome-shell[6136]: [6128:6128:1012/095740.854446:ERROR:account_info_fetcher.cc(62)] OnGetTokenFailure: Invalid credentials (credentials missing).  
Oct 12 09:57:40 tim-XPS-13-9343 gnome-shell[6136]: [6128:6156:1012/095740.900461:ERROR:nss_util.cc(286)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018  
Oct 12 09:57:43 tim-XPS-13-9343 gnome-shell[6136]: [6128:6202:1012/095743.828584:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(228)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.  
Oct 12 09:57:43 tim-XPS-13-9343 gnome-shell[6136]: [6128:6202:1012/095743.828912:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(231)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.  
Oct 12 09:57:43 tim-XPS-13-9343 gnome-shell[6136]: [6128:6202:1012/095743.828965:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(234)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.  
Oct 12 09:57:43 tim-XPS-13-9343 gnome-shell[6136]: [6128:6202:1012/095743.899848:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(238)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.  
Oct 12 09:57:44 tim-XPS-13-9343 gnome-shell[6136]: [6128:6155:1012/095744.885475:ERROR:gcm_store_impl.cc(322)] Failed to open database /home/tim/.config/google-chrome/Profile 5/GCM Store: IO error: /home/tim/.config/google-chrome/Profile 5/GCM Store/LOCK: File currently in use. (ChromeMethodBFE: 15::LockFile::2)  
Oct 12 09:57:46 tim-XPS-13-9343 gnome-shell[6136]: [6128:6155:1012/095746.902726:ERROR:gcm_store_impl.cc(432)] Destroy failed: IO error: /home/tim/.config/google-chrome/Profile 5/GCM Store/LOCK: File currently in use. (ChromeMethodBFE: 15::LockFile::2)  
Oct 12 09:57:46 tim-XPS-13-9343 gnome-shell[6136]: [6128:6159:1012/095746.903244:ERROR:gcm_client_impl.cc(824)] Failed to reset GCM store
```

Comment: One additional thought: the two apps I mention that work (Thunderbird and Firefox) were pre-installed, but the ones that fail (Evolution and Chrome) were installed by me through the Ubuntu Software app.

Comment: There is definitely a problem with Chrome, you can see it in the errors.  Clearly reinstalling Chrome didn't fix it.  What it seems to be is that there are some dependencies that are either missing or broken.  If it were me, I would start googling those errors there especially the ones that include "Chrome" and see what you find.  I would also run the "tail" command with Evolution and see if you get the same type of output.  If you can't fix it yourself, edit your question with what you've done and hopefully someone will help you fix it.

Comment: Chrome and Chromium should have been pre-installed with 20.04.  I think something failed with your installation if you had to install them manually.  I'm running 20.04 myself.

Comment: When you downloaded the deb package for 20.04, did you perform the vaerification checks to ensure that you had a trustworthy download?  The "verify download" option should have been available to you on the site where you downloaded it from.

Comment: Also, how did you install evolution?  I found this command `sudo apt install evolution` from this source "https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254823/not-able-to-install-evolution-on-ubuntu-20-04-new-to-computers-demonstrate-ste#1254824.

Comment: This is where I downloaded and verified my installation from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: I still have the `.deb` that I used for Chrome lying around in my Downloads directory. I can link it on drive. Ive been using it for 6 - 12 months now without issue. I cant remember where I got it from or I would just link that. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newcoming contributor, but I don't think that failing apps were installed from the Ubuntu Software app. If you install these apps via the Terminal or a `.deb` file, that would nicely fix it.

For Evolution, try to manually set up mail settings (following tips from this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+setup+imap)). The Evolution app doesn't support autoconfig (I ran onto same issue as you if I let them configure for me). It's hard for you to do it, but this will give you a bounty of [the app become working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG850.png).

Mentioning the hanging Chrome install, it seemingly occurs because the Snap Store-based Chrome has been broken. I wouldn't like to see that Chrome ran onto the issue, but I would recommend you to uninstall/purge your Chrome install, and then download it from the Web. After downloading it from the Web, open the terminal on the location of your downloaded file, and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Or, other way, open it by double-clicking on it.

Installing Chrome manually from a `.deb` file is much better than installing it from Ubuntu Software (which it's heavily based on Snap Store).

Comment: Those last two sentences beginning with "Please don't take pain while you found me" in your answer don't make any sense as written. Also if there is any toxic behavior it can easily be reported.  With that could you possibly change the wording so that it makes sense or just delete them entirely?  That would improve your answer in my opinion.

Comment: Have you been able to fix the issue?  If not, did you try running `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in an open terminal session and then launch the affected apps and check the terminal?  `tail -f ` will output in real time any errors/warnings that may occur.

Comment: @pphu15 Thank you for trying to help but your suggestion did not fix things, Chrome still hangs.

Comment: Thank you, dumbledad. I'm was running the same 20.04 LTS to try to help. Unfortunately, sadly I can't for Chrome - take this with a ASUS salt.
I would wish that I can remote control, but I hate to perform an remote desktop connection since I wasn't being careful. I would go back and edit if I'm ready.